# Convert Boolean 1/0 to Yes/No

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that will output something like this:

```
1 | 1 | Project A
2 | 0 | Project B
```

And I would like to obtain this:

```
1 | Yes | Project A
2 | No  | Project B
```

So, `1` must be converted to `Yes` and `0` to `No`. How can I do that directly in the query?

```
SELECT 
    project.id,
    project.status,
    project.name
FROM
    project
```

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case`:

```
select 
    publication_id,
    case when publication_status then 'Yes' else 'No' end status,
    project_name
from project
```

In MySQL, `1` evaluates as true when used in a conditional expression.

NB: there is no `publication` table involved in the query, so I can only assume that `publication.id` is actually `publication_id` (same goes for `publication.status`).

Comment: That's an error. sorry. Only one table